# Apache client authentication OCSP responder issue

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ocsp, ssl-client-authentication

I'm having an issue with setting up Apache 2.4.29 on Windows for client authentication with a working OCSP responder. Client authentication works fine when the OCSP responder is turned off. I am also able to verify my client certificate status is "good" when I manually use OpenSSL to make a request to the OCSP responder. This is only an issue when using it in Apache...

**Certificate Authority (I am acting as my own CA):**

- Root CA > Intermediate CA
- Intermediate CA > client certificate 1
- Intermediate CA > OCSP signing certificate

**Certificate Files**

- ca-chain.cert.pem (the Root CA and Intermediate CA certificates)
- intermediate.cert.pem (the Intermediate CA certificate)
- ocsp.mydomain.com.cert.pem (the OCSP signing certificate)
- client1.cert.pem (the client certificate)

**Windows Setup**

- Root CA and Intermediate CA certificates are imported into the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" and "Intermediate Certificate Authorities" stores respectively along with their private key (imported as .pfx)
- Client certificate is imported into "Personal" certificate store along with its private key (imported as .pfx)

**OCSP Responder server**

```
openssl ocsp -port ocsp.mydomain.com:2560 -text -sha256 \
    -index intermediate/index.txt \
    -CA intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem \
    -rkey intermediate/private/ocsp.mydomain.com.key.pem \
    -rsigner intermediate/certs/ocsp.mydomain.com.cert.pem
```

**Manual OCSP request (just to confirm all is setup right outside of Apache)**

- Request

  ```
  openssl ocsp -CAfile intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem \
      -url http://ocsp.mydomain.com:2560 -resp_text \
      -issuer intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem \
      -cert intermediate/certs/client1.cert.pem
  ```
- Response (... represents some excluded verbose output and isn't actually in the response)

  ```
  ...
  Certificate ID:
      ...
      Issuer Key Hash: 6FBE86C0DE4500EE4945D1ECC3E41F9DACF5CEEC
      ...
  ...
  Response verify OK
  intermediate/certs/client1.cert.pem: good
  ```
- The "Issuer Key Hash" above matches the client certificate "Authority Key Identifier" in my "Personal" certificate store, all looks good

**Apache setup**

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10
SSLOCSPEnable on
SSLOCSPDefaultResponder "http://ocsp.mydomain.com:2560"
SSLCACertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/ca-chain.cert.pem"
```

**Apache error**

*Library Error: OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted (log info below)*

```
    1973: connecting to OCSP responder 'ocsp.mydomain.com:2560'
    1975: sending request to OCSP responder
    AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 2, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=Generic Code Root CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / issuer: CN=Generic Code Root CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / serial: B0992B306BCDD3BD / notbefore: Mar 10 21:09:10 2018 GMT / notafter: Mar  5 21:09:10 2038 GMT]
    AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 1, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=Generic Code Intermediate CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / issuer: CN=Generic Code Root CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / serial: 1000 / notbefore: Mar 10 21:20:32 2018 GMT / notafter: Mar  7 21:20:32 2028 GMT]
    _util_ocsp.c(96):1973: connecting to OCSP responder 'ocsp.mydomain.com:2560'
    _util_ocsp.c(124):1975: sending request to OCSP responder
    _util_ocsp.c(234): 1981: OCSP response header: Content-type: application/ocsp-response
    _util_ocsp.c(234): 1981: OCSP response header: Content-Length: 2270
    _util_ocsp.c(282): 1987: OCSP response: got 2270 bytes, 2270 total
    1925: failed to verify the OCSP response
    Library Error: error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted
    AH02276: Certificate Verification: Error (50): application verification failure [subject: CN=Generic Code Intermediate CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / issuer: CN=Generic Code Root CA,O=Generic Code,ST=New York,C=US / serial: 1000 / notbefore: Mar 10 21:20:32 2018 GMT / notafter: Mar  7 21:20:32 2028 GMT]
    2008: library error 1 in handshake (server localhost:443)
    Library Error: error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
    1998: Connection closed to child 38 with abortive shutdown (server localhost:443)
```

**OCSP Responder Server error response when Apache hits it**

- Response (... represents some excluded verbose output and isn't actually in the response)

  ```
  ...
  Certificate ID:
      ...
      Issuer Key Hash: 79D4440D1471385397B194EF1038CEEEEFBBAC24
      ...
  Cert Status: unknown
  ...
  ```
- The "Issuer Key Hash" above matches the *Root CA* certificate "Authority Key Identifier" in my "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" certificate store, WTF? Why?

Can anyone see anything wrong with what I have done or know why this isn't working?

Comment: it seems that the ocsp verification of the intermediate CA is failing(not the client certificate). Is your OCSP server able to verify the intermediate certificate directly if you execute the request using openssl?.

Comment: In the "Manual OCSP request" in my example above see I pass the "issuer" flag with the  intermediate certificate. Is that what you mean by verify the intermediate certificate directly?

Comment: No, I mean to verify the intermediate as "cert" and the root CA as "issuer". it seems that apache sends two requests, one for the certificate and another for the intermediate. Check if the second one works properly

Comment: Hi, I got the same error as Apache, root ca not trusted. Thanks for the tip so I will debug this further. Do you know why that would happen?

Comment: Should also be noted I didn't setup the intermediate CA to be checked against any OCSP responder. The Root CA cert itself has it's own "index.txt" (IE: database) of certificate information separate from the Intermediate CA's (the CA which the client certificates are issued) -- also when using OpenSSL directly it's not making this second request to verify the Intermediate CA certificate against the OCSP responder, do you know why Apache doing that?

Comment: Reading the mod_ssl docs closer says SSLOCSPEnable verifies the entire client certificate chain and I don't see a way to turn any part of the chain off from the OCSP check (the Intermediate and Root CA weren't explicitly setup to have any type of OCSP check) -- I guess I need to go back and set all that up and re-run my test, seems less than ideal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.

- Reissue the Intermediate CA with OCSP information
- Setup a second OCSP responder for the OCSP information on Intermediate CA, the second OCSP responder signing certificate was signed by the Root CA
- Re run the test and now everything is fine

Looks like mod_ssl has to verify the entire certificate chain instead of stopping at the client cert itself. I wish it was configurable but it isn't at this time...